# Does Java optimize loop checks?

Tags: java

if I have the following code:

```
int p=something
int l=somethingelse

int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<p-l;i++)
    sum+=(~i)^2+1337
```

can I generally assume the compiler optimizes the code so that p-l aren't recalculated every loop and is just cached since neither is changed in the loop? Or do I have to put p-l into a seperate variable if I want optimal performance?

Comment: You can check it for yourself by compiling and then decompiling. My guess is that it will not. What if `p` and `l` gets modified by another thread while the loop is running? If you make `p` and `l` `final` though, the  compiler might do something different.

Comment: What do you mean by *every loop*? Is this part of a function that is being called?

Comment: compile it and have a look!

Comment: Optimal performance is hardly ever the right goal. Aim for readability and clarity. They're far, far, *far* more important. Arbitrary microoptimizations are anathema to readability.

Comment: @jrook it has to check the loop condition every time to see if it needs to exit the loop, so it has to recalculate p-l